# Search value in JSON and return to console

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, object

I am trying to search a value in a JSON file using a input field from the user through the browser.

A sample JSON object from the array of objects looks like this:

[image]

I have an event listener to wait for click from the user. After the user clicks the function will go to the api json site and retrieve all the data.

Next I would like to search through that JSON data for what the user typed in.

Example:

[image]

user input: "Cannonball"

expected output: 196 (buy_average)

However I am unable to figure out how to search through the object array.

**Here's what I got:**

the parameter "data" is the JSON objects that was retrieved from API. I know that works properly because I'm able to display it in the console.

```
function renderHTML(data) {
  var searchVal = document.getElementById("search").value;
  console.log(searchVal);
  for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if (data["i"].name == searchVal) {
      console.log(data["i"].buy_average);
    }
  }
};
```

As of right now I'm just trying to figure how to look through an object array after retrieving it from the web and display it to the console.

When I click on the button nothing in the console appears to be happening except for the user's input. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If data is an object, the `length` property will give you `undefined`. You can get the values using Object.values() and then iterate over the properties.

```js
let data = {
    0:{        id:0,name:"aa"    },
    1:{        id:1,name:"Cannonball"},
    2:{        id:2,name:"xx"    },
};

let searchVal = "Cannonball";
Object.values(data).forEach(e=>{
   if(e.name === searchVal){
       console.log("This is the object: ");
       console.log(e);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try *not* using `i` as a string - use it as an integer instead:

```
if (data[i].name == searchVal) {
  console.log(data[i].buy_average);
}
```

Comment: to access the object (which I've done using console.log) you do data["2"].buy_average, which will output 196. I figure I should input the index variable "I" in quotations to access it the same way. Either way it didn't work when I got rid of the quotes.

Comment: Well, from looking at your code it should work - maybe you missed a quote? Try adding a few more debugging console.logs to see if anything weird is happening at a certain step.